# WSO2 AM - Store generates invalid zip when downloading client sdk for an api

Tags: wso2-api-manager

The problem with the zipfiles is that the file begins with a line feed (LF).
If I remove the leading whitespace I can extract the content.

Steps to reproduce

1. Go to the store
2. Click on the api
3. Click on the SDKs-tab
4. Download any client
5. Try to open zip

`OS: Windows Server 2016
WSO2 AM: 2.2.0
Java: 1.8.0_171`

Is there some work around for this? I guess it's due to the fact that it's running on windows.

Answer (score 1):

now i find the reason why the zip file with a LF....
in the /repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/modules/util/util.jag    end of the file there are two blank lines(line 83 and line 84). 
just delete it ..
because of these blank, when manager.jag get the module util, it also get the blank(LF)...

Answer (score 0):

Does this LF is not a "UTF-BOM" character ? Do you have any proxy of any kind in topology (webserver, loadbalancer,etc) ?

Comment: No proxy or anything it's just the local network. It's the same if I start a server on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

i hava same problem, my environment is below.
OS: linux
WSO2 AM: 2.2.0
Java: 1.8.0_171

and i try to deal with that, but just find the bug may be in sdk-create.jag

**var apiResult = jagg.module("api").getAPIDescription({
    name:apiName,
    version:apiVersion,
    provider:apiProvider
}, user.username);**

if (apiResult.error) {
   print({
         error:true,
         message:msg.error.forbidAction(action)
    });
    return;
}

mod = jagg.module("sdk");
result = mod.generateClientSDK(language, apiName, apiVersion, apiProvider);

I find after this code, the zip begins with a line feed (LF), and if i delete this code, the zip i download is okay. So, what should i do... the code follow i think is trying to authenticate user's right to access API?